# Is there a general way of transforming a Future[Reader[A, X]] to Reader[A, Future[X]]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Such a transformation is possible for any functor, not only `Future`:

```
implicit class RichFunctorReader[F[_]: Functor, A, B](fr: F[Reader[A, B]]) {
  def toReaderFunctor: Reader[A, F[B]] = Reader { a => fr.map(_.run(a)) }
}
```

I'm wondering if it is a special property of the `Reader` monad, or is there a more general concept which makes this possible?

It doesn't work when we generalize `Reader` to a `Kleisli`, for example, so I'm suspecting `Reader` is a "special case" here.

Comment: That's called `sequence`, when you're swapping two types, `F[G[A]] => G[F[A]]`. On why it's possible to do that without a `Traverse` instance:
I'm not exactly sure if that's the correct reasoning, but what you're doing is +/- `point(fr.map(copoint))`, so you'd need the `point` from a `Monad` and a `copoint` from the corresponding `Comonad`... although I'm not entirely sure if that's a valid argument, because you can only construct the `copoint` locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This property of `Reader` is called [`Distributive`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Distributive.scala). The `cosequence` method implements your transformation.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Do you know if there's a reason why there's no `Distributive` in Scalaz for `Reader`? There's one for `Kleisli`, but it requires the nested type constructor to be distributive, which isn't the case here. Writing one by hand works: https://gist.github.com/adamw/65eb05116de6628719f0c438c8fe6ee7

Comment: Although ... in the `Reader` case, the type constructor in `Kleisli` is `Id`, which (I think?) is obviously distributive? But for some reason adding an implicit `Distributive[Id]` doesn't make the `KleisliInstances11.kleisliDistributive` "catch".